# Atomic write of nearby one-byte variables

Tags: multithreading, x86, locking, atomic

Suppose, on a multiprocessor machine, there are two global variables A and B, each one byte in size, located near each other in memory, and two CPUs executing the following code.

CPU 1:

```
read A
calculate new value
write A
```

CPU 2:

```
read B
calculate new value
write B
```

Just looking at what would tend to physically happen, we would expect the above would be incorrect without any explicit locking because A and B could be in the same cache line, and CPU 1 needs to read the entire cache line, change the value of a single byte and write the line again; if CPU 2 does its read-modify-write of the cache line in between, the update to B could be lost. (I'm assuming it doesn't matter what order A and B are updated in, I'm only concerned with making sure neither update is lost.)

But x86 guarantees this code is okay. On x86, a write to a single variable only becomes non-atomic if that variable is misaligned or bigger than the CPU word size.

Does an x86 CPU automatically carry out extra locking on the front side bus in order to make such individual variable updates, work correctly without explicit locking?

Answer (score 2):

This code is correct because of cache coherency protocol. When CPU1 modifies cache line, this line became Invalid in the cache of CPU 2, and CPU 2 can't write B and must wait (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESIF_protocol for the state machine).

So no updates are lost, and no bus locks required.

Comment: Could you please explain why you think so? Without cache coherency, updated cache line overwrites old one in main memory, so old content is lost. I fixed such kind of bugs back then, what's wrong with that picture?

Comment: My statement is based on the assumption that the pseudo code in the question is related to the C/C++ memory model. The C++ standard is explicit about it in par. 1.7.3 (see my answer). What platform were you working on for those bug fixes ?

Comment: Cache coherency keeps data synchronized between CPU caches. In this case each CPU only reads/writes its own variable; that would even work if that variable was not synchronized with other CPU's.. But it is almost a moot point since systems without cache coherency are virually non-existent.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I suppose it was asked about general computer architecture topic, like "which part of hardware prohibits cleanly invalid overrun when same cache line used by different CPUs". I.e., there is no front side buses in C++ standard.


Important to know that that's not "locking on the front side bus" but rather per-cache line granularity support.

Comment: _What platform were you working on for those bug fixes ?_

It was INMOS transputer and Intel i860 sharing RAM. Transputer has no caches in modern sense, but i860 has.

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct because the standard provides the following guarantee (1.7.3):

> Two or more threads of execution can access separate memory locations without interfering with each other.

It is possible that the variables share the same cache line. That may lead to *false sharing*, i.e. each core invalidates the cache line upon a write and
other cores that access the same cache line will have to get their data from memory higher up in the chain.

That will slow things down, but from a correctness point of view, *false sharing* is irrelevant since separate memory locations can still be accessed without synchronization.

Comment: This question isn't tagged with any particular language. The quote you have is related to _C++_ abstract machine, but how that abstract machine maps to the underlying target processor architecture is an implementation detail of the compiler itself. So although the _C++_ abstract machine may make that guarantee, the underlying processor may do otherwise. It is up to the code generator to map the semantics of the abstract machine onto the target architecture.

Comment: You make a good point, I missed the tag.. This one slipped through my filter